# bbPress how to sort users by most created Topics?

Tags: wordpress, function, ranking, bbpress

I am using Wordpress and bbPress as a Forum. I want to list 5 Users by most created Topics. Is that Possible?

I have searched for it but doesnt found such an Plugin anywhere.